# Trying to compile GNU Screen

Tags: software-installation, compiling, gnu-screen, c

I am trying to compile GNU Screen in my home folder on a machine where I don't have super user rights. I am taking GNU Screen version used by [Linux from Scratch](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/screen.html).

```
tar xvzf screen-4.3.1.tar.gz
cd screen-4.3.1
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

Its all good until that point and the Makefile is generated. Then the command `make` exists with

```
utmp.c:99:1: warning: "pututline" redefined
In file included from screen.h:30,
                 from utmp.c:34:
os.h:262:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
utmp.c: In function 'makedead':
utmp.c:602: error: 'struct __exit_status' has no member named 'e_termination'
utmp.c:603: error: 'struct __exit_status' has no member named 'e_exit'
make: *** [utmp.o] Error 1
```

After compiling a few files successfully.

Any ideas?

The code line it refers to looks like this

```
static void
makedead(u)
struct utmp *u;
{
  u->ut_type = DEAD_PROCESS;
#if (!defined(linux) || defined(EMPTY)) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)
  u->ut_exit.e_termination = 0;   // Line 602
  u->ut_exit.e_exit = 0;          // Line 603
#endif
#if !defined(sun) || !defined(SVR4)
  u->ut_user[0] = 0;    /* for Digital UNIX, kilbi@rad.rwth-aachen.de */
#endif
}
```

I am on a linux machine though:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.5 (Tikanga)
```

Comment: I guess you need to install libc6-dev library if its not installed.

Comment: Thanks! As I said I don't have super user rights. Building that and all it's dependencies is tough isn't it?

Comment: It is weird though because LFS lists it as having no mandatory dependencies (I guess that excludes fundamental building libraries) ... That's I picked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a few dependencies. That would be a bug in the configure script. You might want to file a bugreport to the `screen` maintainers.